# set id to img using jQuery each

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm triyng to set id's to my img's tags using jQuery each(), but i don't know why it's not working.

```
<div class="row" id="album">
    <a class="col-md-4 picture" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>
    <a class="col-md-4 picture" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>
    <a class="col-md-4 picture" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>


    <a class="col-md-4 picture">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>
    <a class="col-md-4 picture">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>
    <a class="col-md-4 picture">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>

</div>
```

I searched how to use each(), but when i load the page, the img's tag don't have any id.

```
$('#album img').each( function(index){
    $(this).attr("id", index);
  });
```

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: It’s probably because you can’t start ids with numbers.

Comment: Are you sure ? Because the examples that I saw use the index variable to set te id, like $(this).attr("id", "id" + index);

Comment: Ah it seems my comment is outdated. You should be ok with html5. More info: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me are you wrapping it in a ready function to make sure the DOM is ready? $() or $.ready() takes a function that runs once the DOM is ready, running before the DOM is ready and your selectors wont find anything.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#album img').each( function(index){
        $(this).attr("id", index);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="album">
    <a class="col-md-4 picture" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>
    <a class="col-md-4 picture" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>
    <a class="col-md-4 picture" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>


    <a class="col-md-4 picture">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>
    <a class="col-md-4 picture">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>
    <a class="col-md-4 picture">
      <img src="link" class="img-fluid rounded">
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, all my codes are inside $(document).ready(function() { //codes });